# Mounting a SharedVolumeClaim spawns two Pods

Tags: kubernetes

I want to share files between two containers in Kubernetes. Therefore I created a SharedVolumeClaim, which I plan to mount in both containers. But for a start, I tried to mount it in one container only. Whenever I deploy this, two Pods get created.

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep frontend
dev-frontend-84ca5d6dd6-8n8lf               0/1     ContainerCreating   0          18h
dev-frontend-b4959fb97-f9mgw                1/1     Running             0          18h
```

The first container is stuck in creating because it can not access the SharedVolume (`Volume is already attached by pod fresh-namespace/dev-frontend-b4959fb97-f9mgw`).
But when I remove the code that mounts the volume into the container and deploy again, only one container is created. This also happens if I start with a completely new namespace.

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep frontend
dev-frontend-587bc7f359-7ozsx               1/1     Running   0          5m
```

Why does the mount spawn a second pod as it should only be one?

Here are the relevant parts of the deployment files:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: shared-file-pvc
  labels:
    app: frontend

spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

metadata:
  name: dev-frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
    environment: dev

spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
      environment: dev

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
        environment: dev

    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: shared-files
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: shared-file-pvc

      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: some/registry/frontend:version
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 100Mi
              cpu: 250m
            limits:
              memory: 300Mi
              cpu: 750m
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-files             <!-- works if I remove -->
              mountPath: /data/shared-files  <!-- this two lines -->
---
```

Can anybody help me, what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once you have deployed the PVC, could you mind run the get command to view the status of the PVC?
Is it really under RWM mode?

Comment: `shared-file-pvc   Bound    pvc-3147012f-29e6-412d-b904-4c23e466a575   100Mi      RWX            ceph-san       14d`. It is `RWX`, so yes.

Comment: What is your default storage class? If you are using public cloud, please let us know which cloud you are using. In general, the default storage class will not have the RWX mode.

Comment: You can not have one volume claim on two pods. I have seen this achieved with NFS vollumes.

Comment: You want share between 2 containers or 2 pods? This is working as intended. In [PV docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding) you have information `A PVC to PV binding is a one-to-one mapping` so each PV can have only 1 PVC. Please provide some information about your environment. Its On-Prem, cloud environment? How many nodes you have? There are some workarounds like [this example](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/storage_examples/shared_storage.html) but its very specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you check exact names of your deployed `Pods`, you can see that these `Pods` are managed by two diffrent `ReplicaSets` (`dev-frontend-84ca5d6dd6` and `dev-frontend-b4959fb97`):

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep frontend
dev-frontend-84ca5d6dd6-8n8lf               0/1     ContainerCreating   0          18h
dev-frontend-b4959fb97-f9mgw                1/1     Running             0          18h
```

Your `Deployment` is using `Rolling Deployment` as default Deployment Strategy. A `Rolling Deployment` waits for new `Pods` to become ready **BEFORE** scaling down previous `Pods`.

I assume that first you deployed `dev-frontend-b4959fb97-f9mgw` (old version of the app) and then you deployed `dev-frontend-84ca5d6dd6-8n8lf` (new version of the same app).

The newly created `Pod` (`dev-frontend-84ca5d6dd6-8n8lf`) **is not able** to attach volume (the old one still uses this volume) so it will never be in `Ready` state.

Check how many `dev-frontend-*` `ReplicaSets` you have in this particular namespaces and which one is currently managed by your `Deployment`:

```
$ kubectl get rs | grep "dev-frontend"

$ kubectl describe deployment dev-frontend | grep NewReplicaSet
```

This two commands above should give you the idea which one is new and which one is old.

I am not sure which `StorageClass` you are using, but you can check it using:

```
$ kubectl describe pvc shared-file-pvc | grep "StorageClass"
```

Additionally check if created `PV` really support `RWX` Access Mode:

```
$ kubectl describe pv <PV_name> | grep "Access Modes"
```

Main concept is that `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` are mapped one-to-one. This is described in [Persistent Volume - Binding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding) documentation.

However, if your `StorageClass` is configured correctly, it is possible to have two or more containers using the same `PersistentVolumeClaim` that is **attached to the same mount on the back end**.

The most common examples are [NFS](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/storage_examples/shared_storage.html) and [CephFS](https://blog.codegiant.io/how-to-deploy-a-ceph-cluster-on-kubernetes-with-rook-daf24e6db914)